# background text for @Html.EditorFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to add some background text, ideally a prefix and suffix for @Html.EditorFor?

So if you I was rendering a page for someone to enter a company e-mail address or new AD name I'd like it so the ad box would have a persisted background prefix of

```
Domian\
```

And the cursor to start after the \

The e-mail to have persisted

```
@company.com
```

and the cursor to start before the @

The value doesn't have to be captured, just there and unchangeable.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery Masked Input, that'll give you the desired approach: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

Comment: you can display it as Domian\ then the textbox or you can add the desired prefix/suffix at the controller's end ,wither of  which would be easier way around

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look

Comment: EditorFor isn't a textbox, it's an editor. That could be a textbox, but can also be something else. That means that background text for EditorFor doesn't make sense because it can be made up of different controls with different ways of adding text to it.